# Leaflet.js: draw objects into PostGIS database, through Leaflet.draw, WFS-T plugin, GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, wfs, wfs-t

I'm trying to draw objects from Leaflet (Leaflet.draw) into a PostGIS database. From https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-wfst it's the Flexberry one if I'm right

I enabled JSONP in GeoServer, I created a workspace that allowed complete WFS transactions linked to a specific PostGIS user created through

> CREATE USER drafts;
>
> ALTER USER drafts WITH PASSWORD 'whatever';
>
> CREATE DATABASE drafts;
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE drafts TO drafts;
>
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
>
> \q

I started again using drafts account by **psql -h localhost drafts drafts**

> CREATE TABLE public.sites
>
> (
>
> gid serial NOT NULL,
>
> the_geom geometry(Point,4326),
>
> CONSTRAINT sites_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid )
>
> );
>
> CREATE INDEX sites_the_geom_gist ON public.sites
>
> USING gist (the_geom );

I added sites in my workspace, allowed for any public user to modify this layer,

and created the following page from a Polygon example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.toolbar.js/0.3.0/leaflet.toolbar.css" />
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Leaflet-WFST polygon demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet.draw.css" /> 
<script src="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-easybutton.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-easybutton.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet-wfst.src.js"></script>
<script>
  var map = L.map('map', {editable: true}).setView([48.5, 2], 10);
  // add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var wfstPoly = new L.WFST({
    url: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/ows',
    typeNS: 'opendata',
    typeName: 'sites',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    geometryField: 'the_geom',
    forceMulti: true,
    schema: 'https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=opendata:sites',
    style: {
      color: 'blue',
      weight: 2
    }
  }).addTo(map)
    .once('load', function () {
      map.fitBounds(wfstPoly);
    });
    
    ////// draw and edit
    
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({ 
    draw:{circle:false, circlemarker:false, rectangle:false,
          },
    edit:{featureGroup: wfstPoly } });
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    wfstPoly.addLayer(layer)});

map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer( function (layer) {
        wfstPoly.editLayer(layer);
        })
        
        });
    
    // Save button
L.easyButton('fa-save', function () {
         wfstPoly.save();
     }, 'Save changes').addTo(map);
    
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But newly created points would not be saved. Only points created meanwhile on a PostGIS connection of QGIS are showing up.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point of the research, what was necessary was to

1. globally **allow WFS transactions** in Geoserver for all workspaces

and then in

2. **Security > Data Security** , allow only **ADMIN** to write in the workspaces you want to preserve from external modifications

like **dataspacetopreserve.*.w**  (from anonymous writing) =   only ADMIN and not ROLE_ANONYMOUS